# I cannot determine the error between hyperref and hypdvips

Tags: hyperref, debugging

Look at the following Minimal Non Working Example. It's not correct, because the output pdf will be created. Nevertheless the logfile produces an error. It took me a lot of time and I am still not sure whether its my fault or not.

I have downloaded a brand new MiKTeX 2.9.5105 distribution portable version and updated the package.  I compile with dvi-ps-pdf batchfile

Here is the MWE

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Uses the utf8 input encoding
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{hypdvips}

\begin{document}
\chapter*{Impressum}
\chapter{Zu diesem Dokument}
Dieses Installationsanleitung erläutert alle Themen um den -Client installieren zu     können und ist als Leitfaden mit Zusatzinformationen aufgebaut. Bestimmte abgebildete windowsspezifische Programmelemente können in den Windowsversionen abweichen, gelten aber sinngemäß. 
\section{Symbole und Auszeichnungen}

\section{Want to use command from package hypdvips}
\attachfile[description={MNWEB.log},flags=0000000001, mimetype=application/txt]{MNWEB.log}
\end{document}
```

The errorfile shows the following error.

```
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 25.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 25.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \nameref on input line 25.
 [2


]
Chapter 1.
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
               \@ne 
l.29  \section
          {Symbole und Auszeichnungen}
The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.

! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
               \@ne 
l.29  \section
          {Symbole und Auszeichnungen}
The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.

! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
               \BKM@style@\@ne  
l.29  \section
              {Symbole und Auszeichnungen}
The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.

! Extra \endcsname.
\KVS@ProcessorDefault ...sname KV@#1@#2\endcsname 
                                              \unless \ifcsname KVS@#1@h...
l.29  \section
              {Symbole und Auszeichnungen}
I'm ignoring this, since I wasn't doing a \csname.


! Package kvsetkeys Error: Undefined key `\BKM@style@\@ne  '.

See the kvsetkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.29  \section
          {Symbole und Auszeichnungen}
The keyval family of the key `\BKM@style@\@ne  ' is `BKM'.
The setting of the key is ignored because of the error.

Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

Package atveryend Info: Executing hook `BeforeClearDocument' on input line 30.
[3
```

If no one will see my fault, than it could be a bug, I will report after a view days.

Best regrads

EDIT2:

Compile with this commands.

```
set B=C:\tex\miktex\bin\
set gs_path=d:\peter\Programme\gs\gs9.10\bin\
%B%latex --enable-write18 --src -interaction=nonstopmode --save-size=80000 MWE.tex
%B%dvips -P pdf -D1200 MWE.dvi"
%gs_path%gswin32c.exe -sPAPERSIZE=a4 -dNOSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFileMWE.pdf -c save pop -f MWE.ps
```

Peter

Comment: I can compile your document with `latex+dvipdf` on `TeXLive 2013` on Linux, and with `pdflatex`, when I omit the inclusion of `hypdvips`. I assume, there is some incompatibility between `hyperref` and `hypdvips`. Is there any need to include both of them. In my point of view is sufficient to use just `hyperref`.

Comment: Comiled on windows 7, windows8. All the same.

Want to use this command. See changed Post.

Comment: @ChristianH. i would rather suspect `cleveref` interacting badly with `hypdvips`, than a `hypdvips`<->`hyperref` clash.

Comment: The conflict is with `scrreprt`; if I use `report`, no error is raised.

Comment: thank greg, but I have allready reported to the maintainer of the two packages. The idea, that scrreprt can be the reaseon is totaly unexpected to me. :(

Comment: For some reason, with `scrreprt` the macro `\BKM@currentlevel` is assigned the value `\@ne` instead of the number `1`; since `\BKM@currentlevel` is used inside a `\csname...\endcsname` construction, `\@ne` is illegal because it's an unexpandable token.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error appears when using `scrreprt`, because it defines

```
% scrreprt.cls, line 2874:
\newcommand\section{%
  \@startsection{section}{\sectionnumdepth}{\z@}%
  {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
  {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
  {\ifnum \scr@compatibility>\@nameuse{scr@v@2.96}\relax
    \setlength{\parfillskip}{\z@ plus 1fil}\fi
    \raggedsection\normalfont\sectfont\nobreak\size@section}%
}
```

and also

```
% scrreprt.cls, line 2397:
\newcommand*{\sectionnumdepth}{\@ne}
```

When the bookmark for the section is being constructed, `\BKM@currentlevel` is defined via

```
\xdef\BKM@currentlevel{<second argument to \startsection>}
```

which in this case gives the same as

```
\gdef\BKM@currentlevel{\@ne}
```

because `\@ne` is unexpandable. But then `\BKM@currentlevel` is used inside `\csname...\endcsname`, where `\@ne` is illegal.

Here's a fix (proposed by Heiko Oberdiek): after loading `hypdvips` change how `\@startsection` is redefined with

```
\makeatletter
\def\@startsection#1#2#3#4#5#6{%
  \bookmarksetup{style=pp@bmstyle@empty}%
  \ifx\@M#2%
    \xdef\BKM@currentlevel{1}%
  \else
    \xdef\BKM@currentlevel{\number#2}%
  \fi
  \@ifundefined{BKM@style@\BKM@currentlevel}{}{\bookmarksetup{style=\BKM@currentlevel}}%
  \pp@backup@@startsection{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}%
}
\makeatother
```

A perhaps simpler workaround is to patch `\section` to have `\number\sectionnumdepth`:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Uses the utf8 input encoding
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[pdfencoding=auto]{hyperref} % don't forget the option
\usepackage{hypdvips}

\patchcmd{\section}{\sectionnumdepth}{\number\sectionnumdepth}{}{}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Impressum}

\chapter{Zu diesem Dokument} 

Dieses Installationsanleitung erläutert alle Themen um den -Client installieren 
zu können und ist als Leitfaden mit Zusatzinformationen aufgebaut. Bestimmte 
abgebildete windowsspezifische Programmelemente können in den Windowsversionen 
abweichen, gelten aber sinngemäß.

\section{Symbole und Auszeichnungen}

\section{Want to use command from package hypdvips}
\attachfile[description={MNWEB.log},flags=0000000001, mimetype=application/txt]{MNWEB.log}
\end{document}
```

Comment: And it should be fixed in `hypdvips`: `\xdef\BKM@currentlevel{\number#2}` in its redefinition of `\@startsection`. (Also `\ifx#2\@M%` and similar should be replaced by `\ifx\@M#2%` for the case that `#2` starts with equal tokens, e.g. `11` or `22`.)

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Sure thing. I'll change the patch in my answer. It was easier patching `\section` for the particular case.

Comment: The first patch did not work as expected. Sure, for the MWE it did the work. But it seems to me that I would have to make an other MWE for the next problem.
After trying the patch from Heiko, everything works fine.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: A new version of `hypdvips` has been uploaded to CTAN; from the `README` file: v3.01 - supports newer versions of KOMA-Script (thanks to Peter Ebelsberger for the bug-report and to Enrico Gregorio and Heiko Oberdiek for analyzing and fixing the bug).