# Problem with hyperref and hypdvips

Tags: hyperref, links, dvips

In my table of contents, there are entries that span more than one line. Since I compile with LaTeX -> PS -> PDF, the links created by `hyperref` are not correctly displayed in the output file (pdf). To fix this issue, I added `\usepackage{hypdvips}` in my preamble.

Here is my minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

%\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[breaklinks=true]{hyperref} %breaklinks=true allows link text to break across lines;
\usepackage{hypdvips} %The hypdvips package fixes some problems when using hyperref with dvips as backend driver.

\listfiles

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{A short chapter heading}

    \section{A short section heading}

\chapter{A very long never ending far reaching comprehensive illustrative long chapter heading}

    \section{A very long never ending far reaching comprehensive illustrative long section heading}

        \subsection{Short: Two alternative models for the workforce assignment problem} 

        \subsection{Long: Limitations of the models and potential remedies and extensions} 

\end{document}
```

However, adding **hypdvips** leads to two error messages:

1. ```
   ! Undefined control sequence.
   \tableofcontents ->\backrefsetup 
                                    {disable}\pp@backup@tableofcontents \backre...
   l.15 \tableofcontents
   ```
2. ```
   ! Undefined control sequence.
   \tableofcontents ...tableofcontents \backrefsetup 
                                                     {enable}
   l.15 \tableofcontents
   ```

The output file is created and all links are correctly displayed but the words „disable“ and „enable“ appear in the output file.

The problem seems to resemble the issue that has already been reported [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168144/i-cannot-determine-the-error-between-hyperref-and-hypdvips). I use the latest version of the `hypdvips` package (Version 3.01), and pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (MiKTeX 2.9) (preloaded format=latex 2014.3.24).

The error occurs for all document classes that I tested (`scrbook`, `book`, `scrartcl`, `article`, `scrreprt`, `report`).
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you know, that you can use shorter entries to the TOC by using, say, `\chapter[short_entry]{long_entry}`? The same works for the other sectioning commands. Do you really need such long entries?

Comment: And I just forgot: Welcome to TeX.SX! ;-)

Comment: Dear Christian, thanks for the welcome. Yes, I know about the option enabling short entries, but in my case I have to stick to the long headings even in the table of contents. So I tried the suggestions of Heiko.

Answer (score 5):

This is a bug in `hypdvips`. According to the option settings `hyperef` does not load package `backref`. But `hypdvips` redefines `\tableofcontents` and friends to disable back references there. It uses `\backrefsetup` that is not defined, because `backref` is not loaded.

Workarounds:

- Providing a dummy definition for `\backrefsetup`:

  ```
  \providecommand*{\backrefsetup}[1]{}
  ```
- Options `backref` or `pagebackref` for `hyperref` to enable back references and load package `backref`.
- Use of options `tocbr`, `lofbr`, `lotbr`, `loabr` for `hypdvips`. Then `hypdvips` does not redefine `\tableofcontents` and friends to insert `\backrefsetup` commands to disable back references there.

---

Of course, `backref` should be up-to-date:

The `ChangeLog` of `hyperref` shows, when `\backrefstup` was defined:

> 2012-07-24
>
> - `backref` 1.37:
>
>   - `\backrefsetup` added.
>   - Options `enable` and `disable` added.

Comment: I have written an email to the author to notify him.

Comment: Dear Heiko, thanks for your comprehensive suggestions. All three suggestions work fine for the minimal working example. In my original document, though, only the second workaraound does the job. 
My hyperref package is up to date (Version 6.83m with backref Version 1.38).

Comment: Second workaround (Options `backref` or `pagebackref` for `hyperref`): There is only an error message from `biblatex` because biblatex has an own back-referencing mechanism:             `! Package biblatex Error: Incompatible package 'backref'. See the biblatex package documentation for explanation.`  But this conflict seems to have no consequences. The output looks fine, no matter whether I use the backref option of biblatex or not.

Comment: First workaround (\providecommand*{\backrefsetup}[1]{}):
Causes many errors, each related to citations. `! Undefined control sequence. \Hy@backout #1->\@bsphack \ifBR@enable \ifBR@verbose \PackageInfo {backref}{... l.3 ...63 and 25--27, respectively]{Kerzner.2013}. As each project demands s...
! Undefined control sequence. \Hy@backout ...bsphack \ifBR@enable \ifBR@verbose \PackageInfo {backref}{Bac... l.3 ...63 and 25--27, respectively]{Kerzner.2013}. Package backref Info: Back cite 0@Kerzner.2013' on input line 3. ! Extra \else.` And later: `! LaTeX Error: No counter 'pp@backrefID' defined.`

Comment: Third workaround (Use of options `tocbr`, `lofbr`, `lotbr`, `loabr` for `hypdvips`):
The same error messages occur but the last referring to the counter `pp@backrefID`.
In case of the first and third workaraound, the output file contains an empty table of contents and comprises only the first chapter and the first pages of the second chapter. All the errors are related to citations. I use `biblatex` (with `\textcite` and `\parencite` commands ) as follows
`\usepackage[citestyle=authoryear-comp, bibstyle=authoryear, ..., backend=biber, ..., autolang=hyphen, ..., backref=false]{biblatex}`

Answer (score 1):

For me none of the above suggested solutions really worked. Instead, redefining the following command, that is defined by the hypdvips package, to do nothing made the hypdvips and biblatex packages compatible in my case.

```
\renewcommand*{\Hy@backout}[1]{}
```