# Link in table of content not as big as section header if it extends more than one line

Tags: table-of-contents, links

I have the problem that the links in the table of content are not properly displayed.
If the entry does not exceed one row everything is ok. If it is two rows long there is no link at all and if it is three lines long only parts of the middle row can be clicked.
I do have a few entries that extend over two rows and I would like to get proper links that extend across the full entry. What am I supposed to do?

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[colorlinks=false, breaklinks]{hyperref}


\hypersetup{
hypertexnames=true,
colorlinks=true,        % false: boxed links; true: colored links
linkcolor=black,          % color of internal links
}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\frontmatter

\newpage

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\hypertarget{toc}{}}
\tableofcontents
\markboth{}{}
\cleardoublepage

\thispagestyle{empty}
\mainmatter
\setcounter{page}{1}

\chapter{chapter1 chapter1 chapter1}

\section{Introduction}
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 

\section{Methods Methods Methods Methods Methods Methods Methods Methods Methods Methods Methods Methods Methods Methods Methods Methods }

\section{Methods2 Methods2 Methods2 Methods2 Methods2 Methods2 Methods2}

\end{document}
```

Added - compilation procedure

```
latex thesis.tex
bibtex thesis
latex thesis.tex
latex thesis.tex
dvips thesis.dvi
ps2pdf thesis.ps
```

Comment: How are you compiling?

Comment: I added my compilation procedure to the post.

Comment: Can't you use pdflatex instead of latex and dvips?

Comment: I have eps figures and as far as I know this does not work with pdflatex.

Comment: Eps works ok in pdflatex - they are converted on-the-fly in a current tex system to pdf. Only pstricks and psfrag are a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look in the log (after a compilation with latex) you will see a warning:

```
Package hyperref Warning: You have enabled option `breaklinks'.
(hyperref)                But driver `hdvips.def' does not suppport this.
(hyperref)                Expect trouble with the link areas of broken links.
```

The documentation warns about breaklinks together with dvips too:

> Note for option breaklinks: The correct value is automatically set
>   according to the driver features. It can be overwritten for drivers
>   that do not support broken links. However, at any case, the link area
>   will be wrong and displaced.

If you want to stick to dvips you can try the `hypdvips` package (which should be loaded after hyperref). It will improve the links. But I suggest to try at first if your document can be compiled with pdflatex.

Comment: Including hypdvips works with the minimal example. Unfortunately it dies not with my full document. It seems to be related to backref (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185593/problem-with-hyperref-and-hypdvips). The solutions proposed in the thread don't seem to work in my case. I can try to shorten the toc entries but that should not be the solution. Using pdflatex is not an option in my case as far as I know because of all the eps figures.

Comment: And as far I know eps works fine (if you have current tex system). Why don't you trust me and try it? Your pc won't explode.

Comment: I will give it a try.

Comment: By changing to pdflatex I just get errors telling me that it cant find the "*-eps-converted-to.pdf" files. I know that there are information out there about this issue as well but it just does not seem right to potentially solve one problem by changing the whole setup and spending hours adapting everything (with the risk of other things failing to work).  I have done it so often and it just does not feel right. For now I will just leave it broken as it is and keep working on the content of the work.

Comment: That's ok, as long as you try and not reject a possible solution on something that you heared years ago. And perhaps try to get it working in some small test file - it can save you a lot of trouble if you get the conversion working (and naturally you can always convert the eps to pdf externally with epstopdf).

Comment: I appreciate your support. Most likely I will have another look at your proposed solutions in a few weeks. At the moment I just rank this issues not as high as others. Once I have tested the pdflatex approach I will come back to this thread and give feedback.

Comment: Procrastinating the other issues with this one. I switched to pdflatex and it solves the issue with the links in the table of content. I am using Ubuntu and I had to install "epstopdf" (sudo apt-get install texlive-font-utils). Then I called pdflatex -> bibtex -> pdflatex -> pdflatex and the result seems to looks good. Thanks!