# hyperref and hypdvips again concerning attachfile

Tags: hyperref, hypdvips

According to this task [I cannot determine the error between hyperref and hypdvips](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168144/i-cannot-determine-the-error-between-hyperref-and-hypdvips) I have tried to execute this small piece of code and failed. Compile it with

latex example.tex & 
dvips -P pdf -D1200 example.dvi & 
ps2pdf -dAutoRotatePages#/None example.ps

I am not able to compile this example.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Uses the utf8 input encoding
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{hypdvips}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\hypersetup{%
            pdfencoding=auto,
            unicode=true
            }%



\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents*}{test.txt}
Line 1
Line 2
\end{filecontents*}
\attachfile[description={test.txt}, flags=0000000001, mimetype=application/txt]{test.txt}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
ps2pdf -dNOSAFER example.ps
```

... because Ghostscript's reading and writing access to external files (`test.txt`) is restricted by default.

Comment: Works as expected.:)